# Resize Facebook Badge(likebox) smaller, overflowing content area

Tags: css, facebook, fluid-layout

I am putting a Facebook Badge, https://www.facebook.com/badges/, on my website and having a small issue. All works great except when I scale the browser window down.
The whole website scales down but when the FB Badge gets to a smaller size is overflows the content area of the website and will not scale smaller.
I tried overflow hidden, that keeps it from overflowing but cuts part of the badge off.

How can I put a badge on my site and have it reduce down smaller then it goes?
Or any other simply ideas to put a profile(not fan page) on website.

*currently im using the code that FB generates for your page badge
**it happens at small sizes to those the size of a phone screen size, maybe 400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `<img` portion add `style="max-width:100%"` as below...

```
<img style="max-width:100%" src="https://badge.facebook.com/badge/752661391417624.3596.1521173202.png" style="border: 0px;" />
```